# fail2ban logs IP address trying to access server, enough?

Tags: htaccess, ip-address, block

I have fail2ban and logwatch set up. There are IP addresses that are banned > 20 times every day for trying to brute force (I assume) access the server.

I have added these IP addresses to the .htaccess file within the vhosts folder as well as within the root of the site folder.

```
e.g.
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from env=DenyAccess
Allow from all
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^xx\.xxx\.xx\.xx" DenyAccess
```

(real IP hidden)

The .htaccess config does not stop these access attempts (which I can understand if they are simply trying to ssh our IP address rather than trying to access the site in the browser). Is there anything else I can do to ensure they don't get in? Will they always show on the logwatch regardless of the .htaccess? I have disabled root log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just entered into `/etc/hosts.deny` the IP addresses I want to block

```
sshd: 123.456.789.10
```

And the offending IP addresses no longer show up on logwatch.
This is manual but there are ways to do this automatically. One way is to use the ['recidive' function of fail2ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/config/filter.d/recidive.conf) itself